# Width and Height does not work for IMAGE IN HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a site but I can't set the width and Height for a photo.
In a browser the image has a size but in another has another one.What should i do?

```
<div id  ='start'>
    <img id = 'profil-img'src="images (1).jpg" alt="castronel" width="200"
    height="250">
</div>
```

and css

```
#profil-img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

on Mozilla

[image: on Mozilla]

On chrome

[image: On chrome]

Comment: You have not given width or height to the image. Maybe that's an issue

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I tried in css but it 's happening again and i see like in the photos

Comment: Please add all relevant CSS, did you specify something in CSS for id="start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make quote same for all attribute, and add space between id and src

```
<img id ="profil-img" src="images (1).jpg" alt="castronel" width="200" height="250">
```

instead of

```
<img id = 'profil-img'src="images (1).jpg" alt="castronel" width="200" height="250">
```

You can directly add height,width on css

```
#profil-img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring the width and height in the html why not declare it using css since you are using an id tag `#profil-img`. And id tags are unique aside from classes.

```
#profil-img {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:10px;
max-width:100%;
width:200px;
height:250px;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it's happening again. In mozila look's good but in chrome....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="start">
    <img id="profil-img" src="images(1).jpg" alt="castronel" width="200"height="250">
</div>
```

you can also use it directly in css

```
#profil-img{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 width:200px;
 height:250px;
 }
```